# null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am trying to save a model that has some `ForeignKey` fields as well as some m2m fields.

```
def company(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CompanyForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            company = form.save(commit=False)
            company.user = request.user            
            company.save()
            form.save_m2m()
            return redirect(request.path)
    else:
        form = CompanyForm()
```

although on line 6 of the above code I assign user to the object it gives the error in the title.

Comment: are you sure you have correct value in the `request.user` may be there anonymous?

Comment: Yes I am sure. I didn't post it but this view has `@login_required` decorator and I printed user, it exists.

Comment: Add models.py that may help us to resolve error.

Comment: As far as I understand it is not about the user. user is saved with `request.user` but although not specified in the `models.py`, Company model expects company.id as uuid. And it is not saved automatically. Can this information be a tip about this problem?